# Dynamic change text flutter

Tags: flutter

i added a navbar and i want it to change text instant once you press it. As you can see in the video, you need to press it close it and open it again so it will refresh. what should i add so i can refresh it instantly once you press it? I tried adding a navbar there as you see and i followd this thutorial: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

here you have a video on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQ0aVHJze94&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Can you please add some code, it'd be easier to help.

Comment: i added it here http://dontpad.com/codeflutter123 sorry it is that long, i added some comments so you can see them easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: Use `StatefulBuilder` 
Step 2: move `_onItemTapped` inside `StatefulBuilder` 
code snippet

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            isScrollControlled: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            builder: (context) {
              return StatefulBuilder(builder:
                  (BuildContext context,
                      StateSetter setState) {
                void _onItemTapped(int value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = value;
                    print(value);
                  });
                }

                return Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context)
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EvendWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  // Here we changed!
  String image;
  String title;
  String location;
  String date;
  String duration;
  String genre;
  String price;

  EvendWidget(_image, _title, _location, _date, _duration, _genre, _price,
      {Key key})
      : super(key: key) {
    image = _image;
    title = _title;
    location = _location;
    date = _date;
    genre = _genre;
    price = _price;
    duration = _duration;
  }

  @override
  _EvendWidgetState createState() => _EvendWidgetState();
}

class _EvendWidgetState extends State<EvendWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------here is the list
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
    ),
  ];
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------here the onclick

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {},
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey,
                offset: Offset(0.0, 2), //(x,y)
                blurRadius: 20.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
          child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        child: Image.network(widget.image,
                            height: 180.0,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill),
                      )),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
                    child: Text(widget.title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 28,
                            color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      child: Text(widget.location,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: Colors.grey))),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
                    child: Text(widget.date,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 10),
                    child: Text("Duration: " + widget.duration,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: Colors.grey)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 10),
                              child: Text('Genre: ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Colors.black))),
                          Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                color: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 5),
                              child: Text(widget.genre,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Colors.white)))
                        ],
                      )),
                  Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                      child: Divider(color: Colors.grey)),
                  Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 5, left: 20, bottom: 15),
                            child: Text(widget.price + ' RON',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 23,
                                    color: Colors.black)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 15),
                            child: Text('for 1 ticket',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    color: Colors.grey)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 40, bottom: 15, top: 5),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5.0, left: 12, right: 12, bottom: 5),
                              child: Text("Buy",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                      color: Colors.white))),
                          GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                                    context: context,
                                    isScrollControlled: true,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                    builder: (context) {
                                      return StatefulBuilder(builder:
                                          (BuildContext context,
                                              StateSetter setState) {
                                        void _onItemTapped(int value) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _selectedIndex = value;
                                            print(value);
                                          });
                                        }

                                        return Container(
                                          height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .height *
                                              0.90,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                colors: [
                                                  Colors.deepPurple,
                                                  Colors.deepPurple
                                                ]),
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                              topLeft:
                                                  const Radius.circular(20.0),
                                              topRight:
                                                  const Radius.circular(20.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          child: Center(
                                              child: Column(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Container(
                                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            20.0),
                                                    child: Image.network(
                                                        widget.image,
                                                        height: 180.0,
                                                        width: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                    context)
                                                                .size
                                                                .width *
                                                            0.95,
                                                        fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                                  )),
                                              BottomNavigationBar(
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    Colors.deepPurple,
                                                selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                                                unselectedItemColor:
                                                    Colors.white,
                                                elevation: 0,
                                                items: const <
                                                    BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                                                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                                    icon: Icon(
                                                        Icons.info_outlined),
                                                    label: 'Details',
                                                  ),
                                                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                                    icon: Icon(Icons
                                                        .location_on_outlined),
                                                    label: 'Deion',
                                                  ),
                                                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                                    icon: Icon(Icons
                                                        .location_on_outlined),
                                                    label: 'Location',
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                                currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
                                                onTap: _onItemTapped,
                                              ),
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------here the list is defined
                                              Container(
                                                  child:
                                                      _widgetOptions.elementAt(
                                                          _selectedIndex)),

                                              Column(
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            top: 10, left: 30),
                                                    child: Text(widget.title,
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.bold,
                                                            fontSize: 28,
                                                            color:
                                                                Colors.white)),
                                                  ),
                                                  Container(
                                                      margin:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                              left: 30),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                          widget.location,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .bold,
                                                              fontSize: 16,
                                                              color: Colors
                                                                  .grey))),
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            top: 10, left: 30),
                                                    child: Text(widget.date,
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.bold,
                                                            fontSize: 16,
                                                            color:
                                                                Colors.white)),
                                                  ),
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            top: 0, left: 30),
                                                    child: Text(
                                                        "Duration: " +
                                                            widget.duration,
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.bold,
                                                            fontSize: 16,
                                                            color:
                                                                Colors.grey)),
                                                  ),
                                                  Container(
                                                      width:
                                                          MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                                  .size
                                                                  .width *
                                                              0.95,
                                                      margin:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                              top: 10, left: 0),
                                                      child: Row(
                                                        children: <Widget>[
                                                          Container(
                                                              margin:
                                                                  const EdgeInsets
                                                                          .only(
                                                                      top: 0,
                                                                      left: 30,
                                                                      right: 5),
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                  'Genre: ',
                                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                                      fontWeight:
                                                                          FontWeight
                                                                              .bold,
                                                                      fontSize:
                                                                          16,
                                                                      color: Colors
                                                                          .white))),
                                                          Container(
                                                              decoration:
                                                                  BoxDecoration(
                                                                borderRadius:
                                                                    BorderRadius
                                                                        .circular(
                                                                            10),
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .white,
                                                              ),
                                                              padding: EdgeInsets
                                                                  .only(
                                                                      top: 5.0,
                                                                      left: 20,
                                                                      right: 20,
                                                                      bottom:
                                                                          5),
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                  widget.genre,
                                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                                      fontWeight:
                                                                          FontWeight
                                                                              .bold,
                                                                      fontSize:
                                                                          14,
                                                                      color: Colors
                                                                          .deepPurple)))
                                                        ],
                                                      )),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: 150),
                                                  child: RotatedBox(
                                                      quarterTurns: 1,
                                                      child: IconButton(
                                                        iconSize: 40,
                                                        icon: Icon(Icons
                                                            .arrow_forward_ios_sharp),
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                        onPressed: () =>
                                                            Navigator.pop(
                                                                context),
                                                      )))
                                            ],
                                          )),
                                        );
                                      });
                                    });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 20, bottom: 15, top: 5),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text("View",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              color: Colors.blue)),
                                      Text("More",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              color: Colors.blue))
                                    ],
                                  )))
                        ],
                      ))
                ],
              )),
        ));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: EvendWidget(
          "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: One more thing, as you can see in the static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[ list where i choose what to display for each index, how can i access the price, date and all the variables i defined above because if i just add them there it says that the variable is undefined

Comment: I solved it! i just added the list in the class below! :)

Answer (score 1):

Most Propably the it doesnt update because you dint call the `setstate` method. So it updates only after reopening it.

Even if you have added `setstate`, make sure you update the method inside the setState like this:

```
setState((){_index = index});
```

Did this solve your problem?

Comment: didnt i add this here already?   void _onItemTapped(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = value; 
    });
  }

Comment: yeah! you did it